# How to properly define and differentiate between nodes, processes, transactions & operations?

Tags: distributed-computing, distributed-system, distributed-transactions

As part of my research I need to provide the reader with a comprehensive introduction to distributed systems. I am currently struggling with properly defining a number of the concepts that are recurring in literature on distributed systems and transactions. These are (a) nodes, (b) processes, (c) transactions and, (d) operations. I could really use some help in understanding their correlation, as I seem to continuously mix up nodes with processes and transaction with operations. Any input is appreciated!

I have already tried to grasp these concepts by researching the following literature:
Distributed Systems: Concepts and Design (G. Coulouris et al.)
A brief introduction to distributed systems (A.S. Tannenbaum)

Comment: Node - real or virtual machine.
Processes run on nodes. 
Processes generate and execute operations. Operation meaning is similar to a task or a job. 
Transactions -- operations which could be applied only if all processes confirmed, that everything is OK, or the result could be reverted.

Comment: For instance, you want to send money to your friend via e-banking. The process generates a task which withdraws money from your account. Another process performs this operation and returns you a result. The process generates a task to deposit money to your friend. The third process could find a provided account and fails. The first process sends to the second one that transaction must be rollbacked. And you see, that you left your money due to transactions

Comment: Scientific literature is usually quite diligent at defining the terminology in use. Every serious scientific talk, paper, or textbook will either define the terms, or refer to definitions elsewhere. Therefore, to understand what a term means in a particular piece of literature, you'd best read that literature (and possibly the works it cites).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what type of the ambiguity you exactly perceive in the defined terms and thus it's harder to put the right answer. These terms have the same meaning in the distributed systems terminology as any other part of the information technology science.

To be more concrete.
The node is usually "a machine" which runs one or multiple processes. The process executes operations. Operations may be grouped in a transaction (the transaction is composed from operations).

I just quickly searched in the resources you referred and there is said

> A computing element, which we will generally refer to as a node, can
>   be either a hardware device or a software process.

The node runs processes. But the node itself can be a real hardware (a machine) or it could be a virtual machine - which is a process that runs on some machine (a real hardware).
From distributed system perspective you don't mind what the node is in reality (it's real as the HW or it's virtual as the SW) but it's a "container" for running processes.

Process is "a runtime". It processes something. It can process numbers, data, messages... The chunks of the work that is processed inside of the process are operations. E.g. you save data to a database and you do it as an operation.

The transaction defines a unit of work which consists of several operations. The transaction brings you guarantees over those operations. What are those guarantees depend on model you use. If you think about ACID transactions (as defined in paper Principles of Transaction-Oriented Database Recovery from 1983) then you are guaranteed that the all operation are successfully process or no of them is(A), consistency is maintained(C), parallel transactions do not interfere(I) and you are guaranteed that transaction outcome is persistent(D).